# Show a data from database to a label

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# programming and have a problem retrieving data from database to a label text. Here is the code what I was trying to do.

```
private void label3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=car_rental; user=root; Pwd=; SslMode=none");
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from login where username=" + username, con);

        dr =cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            label3.Text = (dr["username"].ToString());
           
        }
        con.Close();


    }
```

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: @SachithaMarioo - Welcome to StackOverflow community! A clear and concise question will help users grasp your problem and answer it more quickly.

Comment: sry for the delay :( the above code dont have any errors but not showing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is created by the concatenation of a string (username) to another string (the sql query). This is a well known source of problems, going from syntax errors (the engine is not able to parse correctly the query text) to a much worse problem known as Sql Injection.

The well known solution is to use parameters instead of concatenated strings

```
private void label3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=car_rental; user=root; Pwd=; SslMode=none"))
    {         
        con.Open();

        // A single string with a parameter placeholder
        string sqlCmd = "Select * from login where username=@name";

        using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlCmd, con))
        {
           // Associate a value to the required parameter
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;

           using(MySqlDataReader dr =cmd.ExecuteReader())
           {
               // Supposing you have just one user with that name
               if(dr.Read())
               {
                   label3.Text = dr["username"].ToString();
               }
               else
               {
                   label3.Text = "User not found!";
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Notice how I have added the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) around each disposable object required to query the database. This statement ensures that the objects involved are disposed at the end of their use freeing the valuable unmanaged resource kept during their usage.

Comment: Thank you very much really appreciate it.!